# Godot: Build .apk shows the loading image and closes

Tags: android, crash, godot

The steps I did to get this error:

- Opened Godot V4.2.1.stable.official
- New Game
- Renderer: Mobile
- Added Node3D and saved node_3d.tscn
- Runned through the editor, and specified the current scene as main.
- Project->Export...
- Added preset Android
- Error at the bottom: Target platform requires 'ETC2/ASTC'... pressed "Fix Import"
- Pressed export project: saved the .apk file: Success
- Installed it on BlueStacks
- Runned: It shows the splash screen and crashes

I already specified the Android SDK and JDK as in https://docs.godot.community/tutorials/export/exporting_for_android.html

Comment: I have no idea what you might be facing. But a crash should be fixed, please report at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues